# This swimm file is Invalid, how to fix?

Tags: swimm

I'm getting the following error from the Swimm web interface:

```
The local swimm file structure is not valid and could not be loaded.

Please pull the latest repo version or ask the repo admin to verify its status.
```

This happened after I changed one function param on a different branch. How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

I work for Swimm.

When you initialize a repository for the first time, Swimm automatically creates a branch named `initializing-swimm`, where the following things happpen:

- A folder named `.swm/` is created in the repo, this is where Swimm stores your documentation.
- A file named `.swm/swimm.json` is created with a unique identifier for your repository, along with any configuration directives for Swimm.

**We stay on that branch because you're going to be making a lot of small commits, and you might decide to start over after you explore a bit.**

Once you save some documents or playlists, the app will start suggesting that you think about merging the initialization branch back to the main one so everyone can use it.

We're planning on some additional guards to help ensure folks don't wander *too* far down the `initializing-swimm` branch without merging.

For now, what I recommend you do is:

- Using the branch switcher function on the left side repo view, click off of `initializing-swimm` and back to the main branch, and see if you per chance see your document there.
- Try merging the `initializing-swimm` branch to see if it will go in cleanly. That could resolve everything.

If neither thing does the trick - it's probably better to just contact support (slack is the best channel currently) and we'll see what else it might be, but I think based on what you described that this is just a case of needing a merge with maybe a little help so it goes cleanly.